# ImageView visible in ListView on wrong position when scrolling fast, using AQuery

Tags: android, android-listview

I got the following getView in listView's adapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_message, null);
    }

    final Message msg = getItem(position);
    final AQuery aq = new AQuery(view);

    aq.id(R.id.message_baloon).background(myMessage ? R.drawable.chat_message_own : R.drawable.chat_message_other);

    // shared image
    if (msg.getPhotos() != null && msg.getPhotos().size() != 0) {
        aq.id(R.id.sent_photo).visible();
        aq.image(msg.getPhotos().get(0).getUrl(), true, true, 540, R.drawable.room_details_gallery_placeholder);
        aq.clicked(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //show fullsecreen photo
            }
        });

    } else {
        aq.id(R.id.sent_photo).gone();            
    }

    if (msg.getText() == null || msg.getText().length() == 0) {
        aq.id(R.id.message).gone();
    } else {
        aq.id(R.id.message).text(msg.getText());
        aq.id(R.id.message).visible();
    }

    return view;
}
```

The method is actually a longer but this part contains everything related to that ImageView. So, as the title states, when scrolling really fast the ImageView, with "R.id.sent_photo", is visible for a position which doesn't have a photo and not for a fraction of a second, it remains visible (that's AndroidQuery library that I'm using).

Thank you!

Comment: seems you are not using view holder for view, I am sure your issue will be solved if you use view holder, there is much doc available

Comment: using a view holder can solve your problem. learn about it.

Comment: how does a viewHolder stop aQuery from making the view visible when using ? (see my answer first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not using memory cache:
   aq.image(msg.getPhotos().get(0).getUrl(), **false**, true, 540, R.drawable.room_details_gallery_placeholder);

AndroidQuery somewhere along that image function does the following

```
public static void async(Activity act, Context context, ImageView iv, String url, boolean memCache, boolean fileCache, int targetWidth, int fallbackId, Bitmap preset, int animation, float ratio, float anchor, Object progress, AccountHandle ah, int policy, int round, HttpHost proxy, String networkUrl){

    Bitmap bm = null;

    if(memCache){
        bm = memGet(url, targetWidth, round);
    }

    if(bm != null){
        iv.setTag(AQuery.TAG_URL, url);     
        Common.showProgress(progress, url, false);
        setBmAnimate(iv, bm, preset, fallbackId, animation, ratio, anchor, AjaxStatus.MEMORY);
    }else{
        Bit...
```

So if it got a bitmap from memCache it calls setBmAnimate

```
private static void setBmAnimate(ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, Bitmap preset, int fallback, int animation, float ratio, float anchor, int source){
    bm = filter(iv, bm, fallback);...
```

And filter is:

```
    private static Bitmap filter(View iv, Bitmap bm, int fallback){
    //ignore 1x1 pixels
    if(bm != null && bm.getWidth() == 1 && bm.getHeight() == 1 && bm != empty){        
        bm = null;
    }

    if(bm != null){
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(fallback == AQuery.GONE){
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if(fallback == AQuery.INVISIBLE){
        iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return bm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was got same problem so, i had used following methods in my custom adapter, i got solution.

Add following methods inside your ListViewItemsAdapter:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return alUpgradeTour.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }
```

Try it, you will also get solution.

Comment: wouldn't that be ~ the same as inflating the view every time getView is called?

Comment: actually for every position it would do an inflate and then recycle it only for that position, right?

Comment: Inflating for every position will help. but it is very bad solution and is very slow, not practical

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems that AndroidQuery library don't put placeholder image before download

```
    if (msg.getPhotos() != null && msg.getPhotos().size() != 0) {
        aq.id(R.id.sent_photo).visible();
        aq.id(R.id.sent_photo).setImageResource(R.drawable.room_details_gallery_placeholder);
        aq.image(msg.getPhotos().get(0).getUrl(), true, true, 540, R.drawable.room_details_gallery_placeholder);
        aq.clicked(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //show fullsecreen photo
            }
        });

    } else {
        aq.id(R.id.sent_photo).gone();
    }
```

Comment: nop. I found the issue AQuery, if you use memCache it makes the ImageView visible. I'll post an answer.